# Split all column names by specific characters and take the last part as new column names in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which has column names like this:

`id, xxx>xxx>x, yy>y, zzzz>zzz>zz>z, ...`

I need to split by the second `>` from the right side and take the first element as new column names, `id, xxx>x, yy>y, zz>z, ...`.

I have used: `'zzzz>zzz>zz>z'.rsplit('>', 1)[-1]` to get `z` as the expected new column name for the third column.

When I use: `df.columns = df.columns.rsplit('>', 1)[-1]`:

Out:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 13 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

How could I do that correctly?

Comment: a quick way is to check how many values are returned by `df.columns.rsplit('>', 1)[-1]`. That should be your first pointer to understanding the issue. Also, from what I can infer, you should instead use this : `df.columns.str.rsplit('>').str[-1]`.

Comment: Sorry, it raises an error: `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`.

Comment: my bad.  `df.columns.str.rsplit('>').str[-1]`

Comment: In my real data, there are column names which are not split by `>` such as `id`, so I modify the question.

Comment: that's fine. Did you try my suggestion? Your earlier result failed because you were indexing into the list. The `.str` ensures Pandas knows you are still working on strings and hence gives you your expected results

Comment: Yes, it works right now, :)

Comment: Sorry, one more question, I find duplicates column name after this process. If I want `id, xxx>x, yy>y, zz>z, ...` as column names? which means split by the second `>` from the right side.

Comment: hmm, maybe this : ``data.str.rsplit(">", 2).str[-2:].str.join(">")`` ?

Comment: Awsome, it works, you may answer the question with your code if you like to.

Comment: nahh. it's fine. SO is a good place to learn and share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
names = pd.Index(['xxx>xxx>x', 'yy>y', 'zzzz>zzz>zz>z'])
names = pd.Index([idx[-1] for idx in names.str.rsplit('>')])
```

```
print(names)
# Index(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thanks, but why not `df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('>').str[-1]`, it's more concise, i think.